# Browse contents of ISO 20022 e-repository

Tags: java, eclipse, iso, ecore

I'm wanting to browse the contents of the ISO 20022 e-repository, per https://www.iso20022.org/iso20022-repository/e-repository but I'm struggling to understand some of the steps as I'm new to Eclipse. It's fair to say I don't even know what form the output will take, so I'm feeling blind!!!

Steps taken:

- Installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- From http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars installed "EMF - Eclipse Modelling Framework SDK" and "Ecore Diagram Editor (SDK)"
- Went to File > New > Other > Eclipse Modeling Framework > EMF Project and imported the ecore model, pointing it at ISO20022.ecore (downloaded from the above link)
- Opened ISO20022.genmodel in the panel, went to Generator > Generate Model Code

But I don't know where to go from here, or what to do with the "20200406_ISO20022_2013_eRepository.iso20022" file from the website.

I just don't know what "[t]hen, you have to generate an Eclipse plugin from the implementation metamodel. With this plugin, you can open the repository and browse its content" means or what I would do with it from the link's instructions.

Comment: I suggest that you contact the web site for details. It would also help to have a good working knowledge of EMF - why not do some browsing and work through a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your specific metamodel but the following should probably work.

In the .genmodel you probably want to do Generate All (or model/edit at the very least). Then you want to do Run > Run Configurations > right click on 'Eclipse Application' to create a 'new Configuration' and run it. It should launch a new Eclipse, in which the metamodel is deployed.

In this second Eclipse instance, create a new empty project (in an Eclipse workspace, you can't have loose files so you need at least one so-called project, File > New > Project... > General > Project), then right click on it and import your file (btw if you open the file it is probably just an XMI so basically just a complex XML file) and you should be able to open it (or try using right click > open with > sample ecore model editor). It should appear as a tree.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking for in the model, the site https://www.mx-message.com let's you browse the structure and contents of the ISO 20022 messages online.